# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getItem'

Tags: excel, office365, office-addins

I have the following code:

```
OfficeRuntime.storage.getItem("my-key").then(function (result){
    // do stuff
}, function (error){
     console.log(error);
});
```

No changes have been made to this code for quite some time. Recently, have been getting the error `TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getItem'`

This seems to only occur in Desktop 365 and has affected multiple users, with one user reporting their build is (Excel 365 Ver. 2306 Build 16529.20154). The online version at office.com seems to work fine.

[`getItem` is listed as a valid method for OfficeRuntime here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-runtime/officeruntime.storage?view=word-js-preview)

Comment: How about collecting some information on the runtime `OfficeRuntime.storage` structure by logging it to console? If it is supposed to be as documented but it is not, then finding out what it actually is may help you.